# Sending Row by Row of a dictionary into a function

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary from `class A` to `class B`.

```
Dictionary<A, B> accounts = new...
```

I init it and insert keys and values.

I have 12 rows in my dictionary. I want to send row by row to a function:

```
foreach (var user in accounts) {
    myfunc(user);
}
```

but what should `myfunc` get?

```
void myfunc(...) {}
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: If you hover over `var`, the tooltip will tell you what the type is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void myfunc(KeyValuePair<A, B> userPair) {}
```

Or just "generate method stub" in visual studio (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd>), and it'll *do it for you*:

```
private static void myfunc(KeyValuePair<A, B> user)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might send values as items or you can assign key/value pair to objects types of A and B classes.